# Export HTML to MS WORD docx file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ms-word

I want to export html Table on my aspx page to MS WORD (**.docx**) file. 
I already have code to export **.doc** file but I want to Export in docx extension.

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.wordprocessingml.documet";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=WORK_ORDER.doc");
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.Charset = "";
    EnableViewState = false;
    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter html = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(writer);
    xx.RenderControl(html);
    Response.Write(writer);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: change file name to WORK_ORDER.docx ? Also, you misspelled the content type. It sould be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Comment: Already used the above suugestion but nothing was changed......I am still getting error on downloading file in docx format.

Comment: what is the error? i tried exporting a table using your code and filename **WORK_ORDER.docx** and it worked.

Comment: Try To add Some image urls (with absolute path) in your HTML content and then export the file either with doc or docx extension and check whether images has been exported or not.
Because in my case images were not exporting in MS WORD 2007 but were visible in MS WORD 2003

Answer (score 1):

Considering **the original code NEVER created a real Word file**, and just put a `.doc` extension on some HTML to trick Windows<sup>*</sup> into having Word (or equivalent program) try to open the file (and hopefully render the HTML), it's likely all you need to do is add an `x` at the end of the existing `filename` attribute and you'll get the exact same result you got before.

---

<sub>* Mac OS looked at file headers instead of extensions, so this has probably *never worked* for Mac users</sub>

Answer (score -1):

put

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=WORK_ORDER.docx");
```

instead of

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=WORK_ORDER.doc");
```