# Exporting HTML table to word

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, export, razor-2

how to export HTML to ms word .doc format in asp.net C# MVC ? i ahve been trying verything but i couldn't get it done. Is there any proper way to get it done ? without disturbing layout of table etc ? I am searching and trying since many days but couldn't. Any help ?

Code:

```
<pre lang="HTML">@if (@Item == null)
 {
     <p style="Font-Size:large; color:Red">No Record Found for this User in <span><i>'@ViewBag.Month'</i></span> </p>
 }
 else
 {
    <div class='continer'>
        <div class  = 'header'>
            <div class="emp_inf">
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="title" colspan="2">PRECISE TECHNOLOGY</th>
                        <th class="slip_type" colspan="2">Official Copy</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/csm_logo.png")" class ='titleimg'  alt="No Image"></img></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="midtext" colspan="6">
                        <span class='payslip'>Pay Slip for the month of <b>@Item.Month</b> </span> <br />
                <span>Voucher No. &nbsp @Item.EmplID/@System.DateTime.Now.Month/@System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2)</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            @Item.EmplName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Designation
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            @Item.DeptName
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hours Worked</td>
                        <td colspan="2">@Item.OverallTime</td>
                        <td>Basic Salary PKR</td>
                        <td colspan="2">@Item.NetSalary</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="border-bottom:solid 3px black">
                        <td>Required Hours</td>
                        <td colspan="2">@Item.ReqHours</td>
                        <td>Payment Date</td>
                        <td colspan="2">@System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="td_text_Align">Earning(s)</td>
                        <td colspan="3" class="td_text_Align">Deduction(s)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        @*Earnings Section*@
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Pay/Hr</th>
                        <th>Amount PKR</th>

                        @*Deductions Section*@
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Pay/Hr</th>
                        <th>Amount PKR</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        @*Earnings Section*@
                        <td class="td_height td_vertical_align" width="20%">
                         Hours Worked: @Item.OverallTime &nbsp
                         <br />
                         <br />
                         Overtime:&nbsp  @Item.OverTime

                        </td>
                        <td class="td_height td_vertical_align" width="15%">@Item.PayPerHr
                         <br />
                         <br />
                         @Item.OvertimeCal
                        </td>
                        <td class="td_height td_vertical_align" width="15%">@Item.TotalSalary
                        <br />
                        <br />
                         @Item.OverTimeTotalPay</td>

                        @*Deductions Section*@
                        <td width="20%"></td>
                        <td width="15%"></td>
                        <td width="15%"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td class="td_text_Align">Total Earning(s)</td>
                     <td></td>

                     @if(Convert.ToBoolean( @Item.IsAppr == true))
                     {
                        <td>PKR= @Item.SalaryOvertimeTotal</td>
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         <td>PKR= @Item.TotalSalary </td>
                     }

                     <td class="td_text_Align">Deduction(s) </td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td>PKR=</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                 </table>
                 <br />
                 <table class="element_borderless">
                     <tr >
                            <td class="element_borderless"><b>HR Manager</b></td>
                            <td class="element_borderless">_________________</td>
                            <td class="element_borderless">Net Paymnet PKR</td>
                            <td class="element_borderless">
                             @if (@Item.TotalSalary >
```

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836725/export-html-to-ms-word-docx-file-in-asp-net

Comment: no it didn't sir, it is incomplete